# Отсеивание элементов массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Всем привет. Есть массив `users`, у каждого элемента есть элемент `is_activated`. Не понимаю, как отсортировать этот массив таким образом, чтобы в нем остались только те элементы массива `users`, у которых `is_activated == 0`. Попробовал решить таким образом:

```
this.usersItems.map(user => user.is_activated == 0)
```

Но что-то явно делаю не так. Каким образом это можно решить оптимальнее всего?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может вам `filter` нужен?

```js
const usersItems = [{is_activated: true, id: 1}, {is_activated: false, id: 2}, {is_activated: true, id: 3}];

const filtered = usersItems.filter(user => user.is_activated == 0);
console.log(filtered);
```